# Maths Puzzle - Logic

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

Somebody asked me this puzzle, but they don't have answer to it.

> 1+2+3+4 = 61
>
> 2+3+4+5 = 52
>
> 3+4+5+6 = 51
>
> 4+5+6+7 = 50
>
> 7+8+9+10 = ?

I want to know whether my reasoning and solution is correct or not

- We need to find out what 34 is equal to
- The logic is  4th equation - 2nd equation , then add the result to 2nd equation
- Now, we know what 22 equals to
- Now add, the 4th equation , we know what 44 equals to
- Now, subtract with first equation, and you get what 34 equals to
- Which is 39

Comment: $34{}{}{}{}{}$ PS: the others are wrong.

Comment: I reposted this at puzzling.se here http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25449/decipher-this-modified-sum-operation

Comment: ????? 4th eq - 2nd = 2 + 2 + 2 +2 = -2.  then add to 2nd => 4+5+6+7 = 52.  "now we know what 22 equals to-"  ??? "now add the 4th equation" => 8 + 10 + 12 + 14 = 104.  Now subtract with the first equation => 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 33.  ... I don't understand your explanation.

Comment: Huh?  "We need to find out what 34 is equal to"  Why? where did 34 come from?  "4th eq - 2 eq and ad to the 2nd eq"  Um, that just give you the 4th equation all over again.  (x - y) + y = x ???  Now we know what 22 is equal to?  Huh?  Where did you get the number 22 from?  Where are you getting these numbers?  I have the slightest idea what you are doing. What is the question???  How is 39 an answer?  What are you doing?

Comment: Um.. so you are assuming that  1+2+3+4 = 10 => 61;2+3+4+5 =14=> 52; 18 => 51; and 22 => 50; 34=>x? So you figure $34 = 2*22 - 10 => 2*50 - 61 = 39?  Okay, but why not 34 = 3*10 + 14 => 183 + 52 = 235?  That answer is just as logical and consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

> \begin{align}1+2+3+4&\to\text{One}+\text{Two}+\text{Three}+\text{Four}\\&\to\text{O}+\text{T}+\text{T}+\text{F}\\&\to\text{Alphabet}_{15}+\text{Alphabet}_{20}+\text{Alphabet}_{20}+\text{Alphabet}_{6}\\&\to15+20+20+6\\&=61\end{align}

Comment: That really needs brain - It's so difficult to crack such questions.